# Running docker container through python API with specific ulimit

Tags: python-3.x, docker

Now I want to create a container to run a dummy command inside an image following this simple documentation/tutorial:
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#container-objects

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run(shm_size='1g', ulimits=[docker.types.Ulimit(name='memlock', hard=-1), docker.types.Ulimit(name='stack', hard=67108864)], image='ubuntu:16.04', auto_remove=True,  command='date')
```

Here is the result:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ContainerError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 client.containers.run(shm_size='1g', ulimits=[docker.types.Ulimit(name='memlock', hard=-1),
>   docker.types.Ulimit(name='stack', hard=67108864)],
>   image='ubuntu:16.04', auto_remove=True,  command='date')
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py in
>   run(self, image, command, stdout, stderr, remove, **kwargs)
>       812         if exit_status != 0:
>       813             raise ContainerError(
>   --> 814                 container, exit_status, command, image, out
>       815             )
>       816

Although the following command works perfectly:

```
docker run --shm-size=1g  --ulimit memlock=-1  --ulimit stack=67108864 --rm -t ubuntu:16.04 "date"
```

What is the problem in the combination of options that I used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your python and shell commands are not identical: in the shell command, you are specifying the `soft` limits and in the python you are specifying the `hard` limits. The syntax for the argument to the [`--ulimit` command flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit) is:

```
<type>=<soft limit>[:<hard limit>]
```

And the documentation explains:

> Note: If you do not provide a hard limit, the soft limit will be used for both values. If no ulimits are set, they will be inherited from the default ulimits set on the daemon.

To get the identical behavior, I would try changing your python ulimit declarations to

```
docker.types.Ulimit(name='stack', soft=67108864, hard=67108864)]
```

This sounds like a shortcoming of the [python documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.types.Ulimit), which says only that both `soft` and `hard` are optional arguments.

Comment: You pinpointed me exactly to the right documentation excerpt I was looking for. Your hypothesis was indeed right, Thank you a lot.